# Content Security Policy: Refused to load image

Tags: .htaccess, content-security-policy

I'm getting the following Content Security Policy error:

> Refused to load the image https://www.xy.de/images/icons/shirt.png because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I want to fix this error with the use of my .htaccess file. I tried to set the header like that:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

Header always set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'none' img-src 'self' data:"

</IfModule>
```

This shows no effect, I still get the same CSP-error. What would be the correct way to set up the header?

Comment: _"What would be the correct way to set up the header?"_ - depends. On the context. Which you so far neglected to give us any proper info about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your input and the error message you are likely trying to add a CSP to a page that already has one. Adding another policy won't make the existing one less strict. The existing policy can be found in a response header or a meta tag. You need to identify the policy and where it is set and modify that one. Alternatively you can remove it and use the one you have shown above.